# How to clear a text edit field that belongs from another class

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am trying to clear the edit text field that belongs to another class from another class. How to do this? Example i want to clear the edit text username which is in the Login class from the registration class. I am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear edittext values by calling et.settext(""). Just after successfully login from the same Activity..
This way u dont need to do it from diff class...

Comment: I need to do it that way because. I have a remember me option so on the create of the Login class i am loading shared preferences.This is done if the user has already registered. If the user has not registered i want to clear the edit texts from the registration class. Please tell me how to clear the edit text from another class

Comment: Or by default make ur edittext as empty, read preferences if user registered  then fill record else leave them blank .. setting views content from other class is not recommanded unless it is a inner class

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    public class Registration{

    public Login l;

    public void doEdit(){

    l = new Login();

    l.setUserName("");   // setUserName is the Method in Login class to set Username.

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Login myLogin = new Login;


myLogin.clearLogin();


class Login
{
    public clearLogin()
    {
        textField.setText("");
    }
}
```